# How to use FixedUpdate and Update properly?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

First, I'm new here, so I'm sorry if I make some noob mistake like not saying something that should be obvious like my unity version or whatever.
(And this is my first post so I don't know how to use this, also I'm not English, so sorry for my bad English)

**Unity Version: 2019.4.26f1 LTS**

This is for a 2D project, but the doubt is global, for 2D and 3D.

Anyway, I want to know how to separate my unity code (C#) properly.

For example:
Let's say that I want something like this: (I'm just using invented code to explain faster)

```
if(grounded && PressKey("D"))
{
rigibody2d.velocity = ...
}

if(!grounded && PressKey("D"))
{
rigibody2d.velocity = ...
}
```

So for what I know, FixedUpdate must be used for physics, so how do I use

```
rigibody2d.velocity = ...
```

in a fixedUpdate, but the

```
if(!grounded && PressKey("D"))
```

in the Update?

I only have one idea and is this:

```
private bool haspressedD = false;

Update()
{
    if(!grounded && PressKey("D"))
    {
      haspressedD = true
    }
}

FixedUpdate()
{
   if(haspressedD)
   {
     rigibody2d.velocity = ...
   }
}
```

And yes, this also looks horrible to me.

I hope this example makes my doubt clear enough, you can ask if not.
Another important thing is that I want to use FixedUpdate() because the speed feels different in my game if I change the computer, and yes I do:

```
rigibody2d.velocity = ... * Time.deltatime
```

With some movements work, but not for all of them.

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: What you have described is perfectly fine. If you are worried about having too many key bools, then create a `HashSet` or a `Dictionary` and store the presses in a different structure.

Comment: I'm worried about having too may booleans, because I'll have like 20 of them and I don't think that will be very efficient.
I've never done anything with `HashSet` or a `Dictionary`, how will that work? 
Is like storing a lot of variables (in this case booleans) in something like an array?

Comment: Having multiple booleans will not be inefficient. It could get confusing to keep track of if that's what you mean.

Comment: Hmm, I've always thought that a lot of booleans could be inefficient...
Then, I'll try with this, thanks!

Comment: Something as arbitrary as accessing and mutating booleans will not give a lot of overhead. Generally implement first, optimize later. There is a good chance you will not even need to optimize at all. However, if you have 20 - 30 booleans for input, I would make a structure to hold the inputs to not get confusing.

Comment: You may end with fewer bools of you don't combine your bools in update. Just cache PressKey("D") in update them combine it with grounded/etc on FixedUpdate. Yes it's not the best way to do stuff but it's fine if you still learning Unity. If you want to do it differently you can use the "new" input system that was added to Unity. There its not done by polling the values every update but by subscribing to events.

Comment: If you only assign `rigidbody.velocity` you can as well directly do it in `Update` btw .. it just will not have affect until the next `FixedUpdate`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between Update and FixedUpdate, is the frequency that these functions are executed.

As the name implies, FixedUpdate is executed in fixed intervals. You can adjust this time interval in your projects physics settings.

The Update function however, is called with every frame update. Hence it is directly related to the frame rate, and therefore the time interval here is not constant. Eg. if the frame rate is 30fps, that means one update every 33 milliseconds (1000 / 30). The reason it is not constant, is because the game can experience lag and frame rate drops.

As a rule of thumb, you generally want to do all of your physics updates in the FixedUpdate function.

Because you are setting the velocity property to a constant, there is no need to use Time.deltaTime.

Therefore, either in your update or fixed update:

```
if(!grounded && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
{
   rigibody2d.velocity = desiredVelocity
}
```

Typically, you would multiplying by Time.deltaTime in the Update function to correct for the inconsistent frame rates when for example increasing the velocity or changing position.